# How to recognise 2 Drag Gestures simultaneously in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture, multi-touch

I want to recognise two drag gestures at the same time so I can respond to 2-finger pan and magnification gestures.

```swift
struct GestureTest: View {
    @State var debug1 = ""
    @State var debug2 = ""
    
    var testGesture1: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0)
            .onChanged { drag in
                debug1 = "test1: \(drag.location.debugDescription)"
            }
    }
    
    var testGesture2: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0)
            .onChanged { drag in
                debug2 = "test2: \(drag.location.debugDescription)"
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(debug1)
        Text(debug2)
        Color.red
            .gesture(testGesture1)
            .gesture(testGesture2)
        Color.blue
            .gesture(testGesture1.simultaneously(with: testGesture2))
    }
}
```

I've tried using 2 independent gestures as shown in `Color.red`, as well as using the `.simultaneousGesture(_:)` modifier as shown in `Color.blue`. Neither of these approaches work. I've also tried using 1 `MagnifyGesture` but the `MagnifyGesture.Value` doesn't have anything to detect a pan gesture.

Is there any way to detect two drag gestures at the same time so I can respond to a 2-finger pan gesture as well as a magnification gesture?

Comment: I don't think a pure SwiftUI solution is possible right now. SwiftUI doesn't support multi-finger drag gestures yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`MagnifyGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/magnifygesture):

```swift
// Magnification Gesture
var magnify: some Gesture {
    MagnifyGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
            debug2 = "Magnify: \(value)"
        }
}
```

Comment: How do I use this to detect the direction of the pan gesture?